# Get page by its ID and display it on another one

Tags: pages

I want to display a page with ID=1149 in a particular place on another page. For that I've tried with this:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 sidebarl"> 
      <?php
      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'post__in' => array(1149)
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
      }
      ?>
    </div>
```

But I am not getting anything, an empty page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not getting anything, an empty page. Am I missing something?

Yes, you are.

[`$query->the_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/the_post/) does *not* display anything — it just moves the pointer/key in the posts array (`$query->posts`) to the next one, and setups the global post data (`$GLOBALS['post']`). So yes, in response to your answer, [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) would be what you would use to display the content of the current post in the loop.

But actually, you could simply use the [`page_id` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters) like so, to query a post of the `page` type and having a specific ID:

```php
$args = array(
    // Instead of using post_type and post__in, you could simply do:
    'page_id' => 1149,
);
```

Also, you should call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) after your loop ends so that template tags (e.g. `the_content()` and `the_title()`) would use the main query’s current post again.

```php
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    the_content();
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

And just so that you know, you could also use [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) and [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) like so, without having to use the `new WP_Query()` way:

```php
//global $post; // uncomment if necessary
$post = get_post( 1149 );
setup_postdata( $post );
the_title();
the_content();
// ... etc.

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: WordPress is so popular that there is so much online content related to it that getting the answer from Google is almost impossible. That said, stackexchange and people like you are really amazing! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct answer, but I did it this way:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 sidebarl"> 
      <?php
      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'post__in' => array(1149)
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_content();
      }
      ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the function "get_template_part()". But to do this, you need to create a php-template for your current page and php-template for page 1149. Then, in your current page template, you include another template:

```
/**
 * Template Name: My current page template
 * Template Post Type: page
 */
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
...
<?php
  /* include template from page 1149 */
  get_template_part( 'page-1149' ); 
?>
...
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/